# issue in IE browser while opening a new window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

i have this small piece of code

```
$("a").live("click",function(event) {
                    <% String lifeCare=LifeEventProperties.getInstance().getProperty("lifeCare");%>
                    var s="<%=lifeCare%>"; 
                    var href = $(this).attr('href');
                    if (href.indexOf(s) != -1) {
                        loadLifeCare(href) ;
                        event.preventDefault();
                    } 
                });

function loadLifeCare(href)
    {
        var wnd=window.open('/NASApp/benemain/LifeCareSite');
        setTimeout(function() {
            wnd.location.href = href;
        }, 6000);
    }
```

here in my jsp page i have checked for a particular word in url's using jquery and that word is like "something.com" which i am fetching from property file ,now if this something.com is found in the url which a user has clicked then i am calling a javascript function which then opens a new window with an  internal site url which is taking care of user's session for that page which has this something.com and then i reload the page with "href" that user actually clicked .

**the problem is its working good in all  browser's other IE** and my client loves IE,
IE is directly going to the link which bypassing loadLifeCare method and giving me this error on console

```
The value of the property 'loadLifeCare' is null or undefined, not a Function object
```

can any suggest something why it is happening ?is there anything in this code that IE don't understand ,i am getting a feeling that issue is with window.open() maybe but i am not sure and i don't even know any alternative if that's the case.

please help me and tell me if you need any clarification on anything..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

1. fixed the deprecated `live`
2. used a better method to open windows (yours may very likely give access denied;
3. moved the function to before it is used and wrapped the click event handler in a a load handler

```
function loadLifeCare(href) {
  var wnd=window.open('/NASApp/benemain/LifeCareSite',"lifeCareWin");
  if (wnd) setTimeout(function() {
    window.open(href,"lifeCareWin");
  }, 6000);
}

$(function() {
  $("a").on("click",function(event) {
    <% String lifeCare=LifeEventProperties.getInstance().getProperty("lifeCare");%>
    var s="<%=lifeCare%>"; 
    var href = $(this).attr("href"); // this.href might be useful too
    if (href.indexOf(s) != -1) {
      loadLifeCare(href) ;
      event.preventDefault();
    } 
  });
});
```

Comment: thank you so much ..i was trying to sort this out for last three hours with no success ,but you saved me a lot of efforts,it works perfectly,once again thank you very much of helping me :)